# How to join tables with union ? mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

1. history
2. business

I want to run this query :

```
SELECT name, talias.*
FROM
    (SELECT business.bussName as name history.*
        FROM history 
        INNER JOIN business on history.bussID = business.bussID
        WHERE history.activity = 'Insert' OR history.activity = 'Update' 
    UNION 
        SELECT name as Null, history.*
        FROM history 
        WHERE history.activity = 'Delete'

    ) as talias  
WHERE 1 
order by talias.date DESC
LIMIT $fetch,20
```

this query take 13 second , I think the problem is that Mysql join  all the rows at history and business tables ! While it should join just 20 rows !

how could I fix that ?

Comment: Can you see anything odd in this query?

Comment: Yes! mysql join  two large tables, while it just join 20 rows !

Comment: It can't fetch just 20 rows, because it has to do the `JOIN` and `UNION` before it does `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Barmar, yes so I should do order by before union, but I got Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What should I do ?

Comment: If you need to order the result of the union, you have to do it this way. There's no way to know before doing everything in the subquery which rows will be the first 20.

Comment: @david What are you trying to accomplish with that part of the `UNION`?

Comment: @Barmar, I just want to join the business table when the activity Insert or Update. but when the activity delete I don't want to do join !

Comment: You were missing `= 'Delete'` before, now it makes more sense.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in the second part I want to get the rows with activity = 'delete'

Comment: @Barmar Yes ! that's right

Comment: How many rows if you remove `LIMIT $fetch,20`?
How many seconds for the two inner SELECT queries?

Comment: Ugh, your latest edit adds a requirement that breaks our answers.

Comment: @Barmar Yes sorry ! at the beginning I thought that doesn't matter,

Comment: @Tarh the the first union part take less than one second !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want all rows from history where the activity is `deleted` plus all those rows where the activity is 'Insert' or 'Update' **and** there is a corresponding row in the business table.

I don't know if that is going to be faster than your query - you will need to check the execution plan to verify this.

```
SELECT  *
FROM history 
where activity = 'Delete'
   or (     activity in ('Insert','Update')
        AND exists (select 1 
                    from business 
                    where history.bussID = business.bussID))
order by `date` DESC
LIMIT $fetch,20
```

---

**Edit** (after the question has changed)

If you do need columns from the business table, replacing the `union` with an outer join *might* improve performance.

But to be honest, I don't expect it. The MySQL optimizer isn't very smart and I wouldn't be surprised if the outer join was actually implemented using some kind of union. Again only you can test that by looking at the execution plan.

```
SELECT h.*,
       b.bussName as name
FROM history 
  LEFT JOIN business b 
         ON h.bussID = b.bussID
        AND h.activity in ('Insert','Update')
WHERE h.activity in ('Delete', 'Insert','Update')
ORDER BY h.`date` DESC
LIMIT $fetch,20
```

---

<sup>Btw: `date` is a horrible column name. First because it's a reserved word, second (and more important) because it doesn't document anything. Is that the "creation date"? The "deletion date"? A "due date"? Some other date?</sup>

Comment: thank you for your answer,date is the creation date, but I also want to get business.name from the business table when the activity Insert or Update, How could I do that ?

Comment: now it's better , it took just 0.1535 seconds. so when I should use union and when I should use left join ? union is bad? may I should delete all the union from my project !

Comment: @david: I hardly ever have to use MySQL so I can't tell.

Comment: so, what do you use ?

Comment: Mainly Postgres and Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT h.*
FROM history AS h
WHERE (h.activity IN ('Insert', 'Update')
        AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM business AS b WHERE b.bussID = h.bussID))
    OR h.activity = 'Delete'
ORDER BY h.date DESC
LIMIT $fetch, 20
```

For the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to be efficient, make sure you have an index on `history.date`.